# How to assign delegate through views?

Tags: swift, design-patterns

I'm not sure what this question should be titled. I have a custom stackview which contains views with buttons. Each of these views with buttons do separate things. When I want to add this custom stackview onto a VC, what is the proper way to assign the delegate through the stackview to hear the button callbacks?

Currently I am going through the stackview like so...

This code *works* but is this the *correct* way?

```
class VC: ButtonsDelegate {

    customStackview.setDelegate(delegate: self)

    func buttonPressed(_){}

}

class CustomStackview {
    weak var customViewDelegate: CustomViewDelegate?
    func setDelegate(_ delegate: CustomViewDelegate)
    customview1.delegate = delegate
    customview2.delegate = delegate
        ...
}


protocol CustomViewDelegate: class {
    func buttonPressed(_)
}

class CustomView {
    IBOutlet button

    weak var delegate: ButtonsDelegate?

    @objc fun buttonPressed() {
        delegate.buttonPressed()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Doesn't it work?

Comment: @Ahmet It works, but is this "good" architecture?

Comment: I think it is good. Just you may add a parameter in the protocol function. Then you can understand that which button is pressed and remove the buttonDelegates in the customStackview class. You do not need it.

Comment: Yes, I already have parameters indicating which button is pressed. I omitted them for smaller code to understand.